# Bootstrap hiding/showing a column

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap in my project and given the layout below [available here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bBkYqecRX1PowLB2Aroo?p=preview):

```
+--+ +--------------------------------------+ +--+
|B1| | Search bar                           | |B2|
+--+ +--------------------------------------+ +--+

+------------------------------------------------+
| Results panel                                  |
+-+----------------------------------------------+
| + result 1                                     |
|                                                |
| + result 2                                     |
|                                                |
| + result 3                                     |
|                                                |
| + result 4                                     |
|                                                |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

It should change into the following upon **clicking B1**:

```
+----------+ +------------------------------+ +--+
| Sidebar  | | Search bar                   | |B2|
+----------+ +------------------------------+ +--+
|          |
| +option1 | +-----------------------------------+
|          | | Results panel                     |
| +option2 | +-+---------------------------------+
|          | | + result 1                        |
| +option3 | |                                   |
|          | | + result 2                        |
| +option4 | |                                   |
|          | | + result 3                        |
| +option5 | |                                   |
|          | | + result 4                        |
| +option6 | |                                   |
+----------+ +-----------------------------------+
```

Once the "Sidebar" opens, the "Results panel" and the "Search bar" shrink to make room for it: this is a chance to hide some of the results details just for visualization sake, referring to [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bBkYqecRX1PowLB2Aroo?p=preview) in particular, it should be possible to hide the **Updated** column for example.

Unfortunately I couldn't make things work, as you can see in my plunker, I even tried to nest the result panel within the search bar, but that breaks the initial layout like this:

```
+--+ +--------------------------------------+ +--+
|B1| | Search bar                           | |B2|
+--+ +--------------------------------------+ +--+

     +--------------------------------------+
     | Results panel                        |
     +-+------------------------------------+
     | + result 1                           |
     |                                      |
     | + result 2                           |
     |                                      |
     | + result 3                           |
     |                                      |
     | + result 4                           |
     |                                      |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

Which is something I don't want.

I also found an exquisite angular directive, [ng-pageslide](http://dpiccone.github.io/ng-pageslide/examples/) (daje danié), which shows what I actually need in the **"Push content"** demo, even if, alas, looks like that options could be used just on the `<body>` while I need it to be used in any `<div>` I chose to.

**Is there a way to obtain what I need using vanilla Bootstrap classes, custom mixins and ng-hide/ng-show?**

Comment: Best place would be to go to bootsnipp.com and search for side menu you will find lot of samples I remember seeing one exactly as you are asking for.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use Knockout.js to do a CSS binding on your buttons. You will likely find plenty of other time saving uses for the library if you pull it into your project.

http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: @Reddy thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Korgrue apart the fact I'm already using AngularJS, in the plunker just like in my project, my problem is not **how to trigger** the transformation using bindings of a particular front end framework, but it's about **making it using Bootstrap** vanilla classes or custom mixins, maybe in combination with ng-hide/ng-show, instead of pure CSS transformations.

Comment: may be you can tweak these to your requirement. http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/minimal-menu and http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/svbtle-inspired-menu

Comment: @Reddy Thank you very much for looking for something relevant on bootsnipp, I do really appreciate you effort! The Svbtle menu it's really close to what I need, but it uses pure CSS for the trick, and if I would use that solution, then mine "results panel" won't shrink once the sidebar opens: that's something I imagined to achieve somehow via the Bootstrap grid, thus my question.

Comment: @Gargaroz let me look for more examples..